# Capture what is Rendered in OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es

Im Making an android Game with OpenGl ES, I Want to capture what is rendered onto screen By FloatBuffer and save it for later use, For Example If this is the OutPut:

[image]

I want this for Result (as PNG Image) :

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is on screen won't be a floating point buffer - it's typically RGBA8 unorm 32-bit per pixel.

Capture via glReadPixels to fetch the raw RGBA data - you'll have to supply the raw to PNG save functionality, that's not part of OpenGL ES itself.

Note that this is a relatively expensive operation, especially at high screen resolutions, so don't expect to do this at interactive frame rates.

Comment: thanks, i want this capture to be reused later, i mean i want to capture the rendered opengl and then create a new rectangle with this capture as a texture on it, does i have to convert the raw to a format like png first and then set it for new rectangle texture? or the raw output can be used directly? @Isogen74

and then is there a faster way to do this?